# Help Needed With XML Serializer Error

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

here is my code

```
// Read the data from the file 
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(HighScoreData)); 
data = (HighScoreData)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
```

im currently doing a saving highscore for my game. but it get an error of "there is an error in xml document (0, 0).
care to help or enlighten?

Comment: How are you building the stream object.  Most likely it is empty or not containing XML data.

Comment: If it's a memory stream, there's probably a control character right at the beginning.

Comment: Agreed: how is the stream created, both in this snippet as well as then it's first serialized from the original object?

Comment: Can you post the structure of HighScoreData and the XML file you are trying to deserialize ?

Answer (score 1):

i have had this problem before and a byte order mark was present at the beginning of the file.  Check your XML file in a hex editor and see if there are three characters at the beginning.  You could simply do something like the following with your raw xml

```
if (xml.StartsWith(ByteOrderMarkUtf8)) 
{     
   xml = xml.Remove(0, ByteOrderMarkUtf8.Length); 
}
```

then read that into the stream

or you could do something like this when creating your stream

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml); 
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
```

hopefully that helps

Comment: I do not agree with this.  A StreamReader should be used; it will detect any byte order marks.  Note that there a more than one byte order marks.